# how do i send attachments using lua sockets / smtp?

Tags: sockets, email, lua, smtp

I have the following code:

```
local email_credentials = function(email_address, password, username)
   local from 
   local contents = read_email_contents_file()
   contents= string.gsub(contents, "<<password>>", password)
   from = "<CAdmin@test.net>"
   rcpt = {
   "<"..email_address..">"
   }
   mesgt = {
      headers = {
         to = email_address,
         ["content-type"] = 'text/html',
         subject = "Your Password"
     },
       body = contents
  }

  r, e = smtp.send{
     from = from,
     rcpt = rcpt,
     server = 'localhost', 
     source = smtp.message(mesgt)
  }
end
```

Found this post:

http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2005-08/msg00021.html

I've tried changing the header section to look like:

```
  headers = {
     to = email_address,
     ["content-type"] = 'text/html',
     ["content-disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="/var/log/test.log"',
     subject = "test email with attachment"
 },
```

but that didn't work.  THe email sent / received but with no attachment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

I've added the following two lines:

```
 ["content-description"] ='test description',
 ["content-transfer-encoding"] = "BASE64"
```

and now I get an attachment.  However, the data is all jumbled.  Looks like this:

> =«,ÂŠÝrm/'LŒq©ÚuÜ!j×¯z»^ÆÜÁ©í¶‹aŠÇ¦j)

The contents of the file is just text....
Thanks

Comment: Have you actually encoded 'content' in base64?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  needed to include the library ltn12.

http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/old/luasocket-2.0-beta2/ltn12.html

I updated my code so that it looks like the following:

```
local email_withattachment = function(email_address, path, filename)
   local from 
   if (email_address == nil) or (path == nil) or (filename == nil) then
    return false
   end

   from = "<admin@test.net>"
   rcpt = {
   "<"..email_address..">"
   }
   mesgt = {
      headers = {
         to = email_address,
         ["content-type"] = 'text/html',
         ["content-disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="'..filename..'"',
         ["content-description"] ='yourattachment',
         ["content-transfer-encoding"] = "BASE64",
         subject = "subject line"
     },
      body = ltn12.source.chain(
        ltn12.source.file(io.open(path..filename, "rb")),
        ltn12.filter.chain(
          mime.encode("base64"),
          mime.wrap()
          )
        )
  }

  r, e = smtp.send{
     from = from,
     rcpt = rcpt,
     server = 'localhost', 
     source = smtp.message(mesgt)
  }
  if e then
    return false
  end
  return true
end
```

I'm still trying to read thorugh the LTN12 manual to understand what exactly I'm doing (lol) but the code works.

Hope this helps someone else.